# How to install Quicken 98 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, quicken

Quicken 98 installs fine on Windows 7; not Windows 10 however.

I've tried compatibility settings to no avail.

With Windows 7, it worked provided you picked the win95 folder and ran the setup in there, rather than the root install.exe.  Presumably because it was a 32 bit, rather than a 16 bit installer.

However, this approach just results in a hung instance of setup.exe in Windows 10, whether run as administrator or not.

I can run it in a Windows 7 VM on VirtualBox, if I have to, but I'd rather not incur the overhead.

Any ideas?  Other than "use more modern software", please :)

Comment: Many applications no longer install or work in W10, not sure what you can do. The price of progress.

Comment: It sounds like you are running a x64 version of Windows now, 16-bit applications, cannot be run natively on ANY Windows x64

Comment: @Ramhound its quicken 98 from the win95 folder is 32 bit

Comment: "Presumably because it was a 32 bit, rather than a 16 bit installer." You don't indicate if the program doesn't work or if you fail to even install it.  Either case the program your trying to use is not compatible with Windows 10

Comment: My advice would be not to use windows 10 at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an Amazon review for a newer Quicken version where reviewer "Amazon Customer" stated "I still run Quicken 98 (although a year 2000 compliant version) on Windows 10 and it still does everything I need it to do. I love this program and would feel lost without it.  The windows installer hasn't worked since W7 but it installs perfectly from the CD in safe mode."

If that approach does not work for you, you might try the more complicated approach which worked for me on installing on Windows 7: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/please-can-you-help-me-i-have-an-old-programmes/439fc67f-ee36-4cd5-ab34-e301299890bf?page=2

Personally, I just upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7.  Quicken 98, which was installed on Windows 7, runs on Windows 10 except portions of the display are blank at startup until you click on that area.  The net effect is you are gradually shown bits and pieces as you click on various areas. I couldn't discover a workaround in the QW.exe Compatibility settings (XP SP3) or in the NVidia settings (361.91 driver) so the easiest workaround I have figured out so far is to minimize (WinKey+DownArrow) then restore (WinKey+UpArrow) after Quicken 98 starts. This produces the display as it should have been at startup.

Comment: Fantastic. Installed straightaway after booting to Safe Mode, seems to work as normal.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

1. Create a clean Windows XP SP2 or SP3 VM.  TURN OFF all updates.
2. Download a copy of WinInstall LE (no longer maintained but still works) and install inside the VM.

   - https://www.latcomsystems.com/wp_plugins/WinINSTALL_LE.exe
3. Use it to create an MSI for Quicken 98.

   - Create a BEFORE snapshot.
   - Install Quicken 98 using default directory location - exclude Internet explorer and other useless components.
   - Create an AFTER snapshot.
   - Generate a MSI package.
4. Copy the MSI package to your Windows 10 machine and install there - silent install.
5. DO NOT use compatibility mode for QW.EXE, otherwise the UAC prompt will keep popping up every time you open Qucien.
6. Download and install the Application Compatibility Toolkit (ACT):
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/yongrhee/download-windows-10-assessment-and-deployment-kit-adk

   - Create a new compatibility database.
   - Select C:\QUICKENW\QW.EXE as the target executable.
   - Set the following fixes to true (will prevent Disk Full errors when backing up data files):

     - EmulateGetDiskFreeSpace
     - GetDiskFreeSpace2GB
   - Save database.
   - Install it in the ACT tool (Right click -> install).
7. Copy your old existing data files to C:\QUICKENW.
8. Launch Quicken and open your old data file.
9. Close Quicken.
10. Update VirtualStore - %LocalAppData%\VirtualStore -> Windows -> QUICKEN.INI with settings from old QUICKEN.INI - registration info, etc.  PAY ATTENTION to any file paths and make sure they reflect C:\QUICKENW.
11. To get rid of the screen not painting correctly on program launch, I wrote a small utility to fix that:

- Make sure you have .NET framework 4.5 or later (should be included in Win-10 by default).
- Download https://www.latcomsystems.com/wp_plugins/QuickenLauncher.exe
- Copy to you C:\QUICKENW or whatever folder where QW.EXE is located.
- Change your Quicken shortcut to launch QuickenLauncher.exe instead of QW.exe
- I have not tested, but I believe QuickienLauncher.exe would also fix screen painting issues on Quicken 99, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, and 2004.

This seems like a lot of work, but only takes about 30 minutes and well worth it to continue using Quicken 98, the best version of Quicken ever in my opinion.